# ubuntu 17.04 freezes after safe removing usb flash or hdd

Tags: kernel, kubuntu, shutdown, freeze, usb-drive

My laptop (dell studio xps 1640) is running a kubuntu 17.04 with kernel 4.10.0-42-generic. Most of the times when i connect a USB or HDD device, after safe removing the device when i physically remove the device the os freezes and there is nothing i can do except shutting down the system using power button. It happened before with other versions of ubuntu too, but now that I have a fresh install of kubuntu 17.04 it happens all the time. What do you think is the problem and where should i look for it. I don't have a clue!
It's worth mentioning that i don't think it's a hardware problem because i tested it on windows and there was nothing wrong about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this can help: Install **gnome-disk-utility** by typing `sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility`. Right after you safe remove the device, run this utility **before** you unplug it, select the device and click on the **Power Off** button. This will cut the USB provided power to the device turning it off completely. You should be able to unlpug it afterwards without problems.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It seems that it's an alternative way to solve the problem and apparently it works. so thanks for that.
But still i'm looking for the problem. I'm wondering what the problem may be.

Comment: 1. Did you check with `df` that all partitions in the drive were really unmounted? 2. If there are more than one mounted partitions on a drive, and you unmount only one partition, there are still connected partitions, which might create problems; 3. If you have an entry in `/etc/fstab` for a partition in the drive, and you unplug it, there might be problems. -- But if gnome-disk-utility continues to make things work, whatever is the problem, *that's good* :-)

Comment: @sudodus Thanks for the reply. 1- After  unmounting the partition no mounted partition related to that drive appears in df. 2- There is only one partition in that drive. So unmounting that partition should unmount the drive. 3- I have entries in fstab for automounting some partitions but they are not related to external devices like USB or HDD so that shouldn't cause the problem.
Turning off drives using disk-utility is a good alternative to prevent freezes but it bugs me not knowing what is the real problem and how i can fix it.
I appreciate your help. It means a lot.

Comment: For several years I have been using the command `sudo umount /mountpoint` to unmount a partition in an external drive, and after that [if relevant turn off and] unplug the drive. It has been working well in several versions of Ubuntu. My main system is 16.04 LTS (based on 16.04.1 and still using the xenial kernel), but I have been testing newer versions, and never experienced the kind of problems that you have. -- If you are lucky, other people will add their experiences and help us understand why.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to your issue ?

Comment: Actually no! But after upgrading to 18.04 i haven't had any problems anymore.