# Unpluging external disk causes Ubuntu to freeze

Tags: mount, hard-drive, freeze

I am new to Linux and, despite some research on the Internet, I have not found a solution for my issue.

I have an external disk that I formated to be FAT32. It is successfully recognized by my computer (working with Ubuntu 16.04) but, when I want to remove it, it causes Ubuntu to freeze entirely (mouse and keyboard not responding, clock stopping at time of "shutdown"). This occurs if I actually remove the disk or not, and happens five seconds after unmounting it and clicking on "remove safely".

The command Alt+Syst with REISUB doesn't turn the computer off, only pressing the power button for several seconds does so.

I tried the solution indicated here: [ubuntu 17.04 freezes after safe removing usb flash or hdd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993972/ubuntu-17-04-freezes-after-safe-removing-usb-flash-or-hdd)
but, the application indicates that the disk is correctly unmounted.

I am a little bit confused and a complete neophyte, so I do not understand what the issue is and how to solve it. If anyone knows how to fix this problem, I would be glad to hear from you.

Comment: How is the external drive mounted? Automatically or manually? (Mounting means that the file system in the partition in the external drive will be made available to the operating system.) Do you unmount the file system in the external drive before removing it? In that case how?

Comment: I am not sure I actually get what you are saying, my apology for my lack of knowledge. I either only clicked on "safely remove", or I used gnome-disk-utility and I clicked on "unmount disk". Does it make any difference ?

Comment: Those unmount methods *should* work. You can also identify the drive (for example with `gnome-disk-utility` and then unmount with elevated permissions, `sudo unmount /dev/sdxn` where x is the drive letter and n is the partition number (once for every mounted partition on the drive). You may also need to swapoff, if there is an active swap partition on the drive, `sudo swapoff -a` or specifically `sudo swapoff /dev/sdxn` where n is the partition number for the swap partition.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have the same problem. See this [debian bugzilla report #914948](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=914948) for details and [this discussion](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/system-freeze-after-user-unmount-of-usb-device-with-thunar-4175643206/) as well.

Maybe if you just `unmount` the device (not `safely remove`) and then disconnect it after 10 seconds or so, you'd keep your system up. This seems to work for me for now at the very least.

You may as well experiment with some fresher kernel installations and see whether this fixes your problem or not.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I suppose the common commands upgrade/update do not fresh the available kernel with a new one ?

Comment: Well, when the new kernel is minted and pushed to main debian/ubuntu apt repository for your distro - _then_ it's an ordinary package update, so - yes, you may weather this problem out and obtain a fix when someone's patch  trickles down to general access. If you want patched/fixed kernel running on your machine any sooner you'll need to either register with an experimental PPA to which developers push or install plenty of development packages and build kernel locally from a patched source snapshot.